# Django table with form in every row

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a basic table Name/Property.

I want to add a third column where user can input text.
Once submitted, this text will be saved to the database (with Name and property).

I did some search, but still not sure about what kind of solution should I look for.
Any direction or advice?
Would Django-table2 help?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

This is easily achieved using [django formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/), and read about the `extra` parameter. In your case, you'll have something like `MyModel = formset_factory(MyModel, extra=1)`.

Comment: Even if they are not really dependant? ie User is free to add text for any name. If yes, is the table created by formset itself?